# How to check intended controllers are loaded in WebMvcTest in Spring Boot Unit Test

Tags: spring-boot-test

I have more than one controllers in my Spring boot application. I have written UnitTest using @WebMvcTest without defining specific controller class. How can I check Controller class loaded in the current UnitTest context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you get a Spring Test Context when running `@WebMvcTest`, you can try to inject your controller (they are also Spring Beans) or check if the bean is present inside the `WebApplicationContext`.

The following test uses both approaches:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired(required = false)
  private OtherController otherController;

  @Autowired(required = false)
  private MyController myController;

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  @Test
  void test() throws Exception {

    assertNull(otherController);
    assertNotNull(myController);

    assertNotNull(webApplicationContext.getBean(MyController.class));
    assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> webApplicationContext.getBean(OtherController.class));

  }
}
```

You can also remove `required=false` from `@Autowired` and then your test will immediately fail as it can't inject the requested controller bean.